# Rest API node.js nodemon issue

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I keep having this message

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried to kill processes in terminal but it didn't help at all. Watched a few YouTube videos but still can't figure out the issue.

```js
const express = require('express')
//const req = require('express/lib/request');
//const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sklep') //{ useNewUrlParser: true})
//ROUTES
//app.get('/', (req,res) => {
//    res.send('we are on home');
//});
//how to lisen to server
///const db = mongoose.connection('mongodb://localhost/bazaDanych')
///db.on('error',(error) => console.error(error))
///db.once('open',() => console.log('connected to database'))
db.on('connected', () => console.log('Connected to database'))
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'))
```

Comment: Any additional info in the terminal? What is `db`? You didn't declare `db` anywhere

Comment: Your server is throwing an error (what error typically will also be written in the terminal) that causes it to crash. And nodemon waits until you fix that error, because unless the error is fixed, it makes no sense to restart the server, as it will likely crash again ...